# Variable JSX into render dangerouslySetInnerHTML()

Tags: reactjs

I need to insert a variable into dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

```js
import serviceAPI from "serviceAPI";
const [content,setContent] = useState("");
const [firstName,setFirstName] = useState("Thomas");

    useEffect(() => {
         fetchContent()
     }, [])
     
     const fetchContent = async () => {
     // Return string : "<h1>Hello {firstName}</h1>"
     const result = await serviceAPI.getContent()
     setContent(text)
     }
    return (
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content.toString() }}></p>
    )
```

The result of this code: `Hello {firstName}`

The result I need: `Hello Thomas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string interpolation or simple concatination to insert the variable into the string:

```js
const text = `<h1>Hello ${firstName}</h1>`
```

Also, you'll want to add firstName to the dependencies list of useEffect.

In your code example, you don't need to use `useEffect`, I would change it to:

```
const [firstName,setFirstName] = useState("Thomas")
const content = `<h1>Hello ${firstName}</h1>`
 
return (
  <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />
)
```

---

In case the string is returned from an API, you could use a regex search and replace:

```js
const text = "<h1>Hello {firstName}</h1>"
const newText = text.replace(/{firstName}/g, firstName)
```